# heroku-toolbelt 3.23.3 broken on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am experiencing a problem with the heroku toolkit on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. Whenever I run any heroku command, I get the following:

```
panic: user: Current not implemented on linux/amd64

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.homeDir(0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/jdickey/src/github.com/heroku/heroku-cli/filesystem.go:17 +0x75
main.init()
    /Users/jdickey/src/github.com/heroku/heroku-cli/filesystem.go:9 +0x148

goroutine 2 [runnable]:
runtime.forcegchelper()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:90
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1

goroutine 3 [runnable]:
runtime.bgsweep()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/runtime/mgc0.go:82
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1

goroutine 4 [runnable]:
runtime.runfinq()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/runtime/malloc.go:712
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1

goroutine 5 [runnable]:
github.com/stvp/rollbar.func·001()
    /Users/jdickey/src/github.com/stvp/rollbar/rollbar.go:73
created by github.com/stvp/rollbar.init·1
    /Users/jdickey/src/github.com/stvp/rollbar/rollbar.go:78 +0x5f
error loading plugin topics
panic: user: Current not implemented on linux/amd64

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.homeDir(0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/jdickey/src/github.com/heroku/heroku-cli/filesystem.go:17 +0x75
main.init()
    /Users/jdickey/src/github.com/heroku/heroku-cli/filesystem.go:9 +0x148

goroutine 2 [runnable]:
runtime.forcegchelper()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:90
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1

goroutine 3 [runnable]:
runtime.bgsweep()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/runtime/mgc0.go:82
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1

goroutine 4 [runnable]:
runtime.runfinq()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/runtime/malloc.go:712
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1

goroutine 5 [runnable]:
github.com/stvp/rollbar.func·001()
    /Users/jdickey/src/github.com/stvp/rollbar/rollbar.go:73
created by github.com/stvp/rollbar.init·1
    /Users/jdickey/src/github.com/stvp/rollbar/rollbar.go:78 +0x5f
error loading plugin commands
```

My user account is NOT jdickey and I am on Linux, not OS X. So what this looks like to my eye as a programmer is that there are some compiled in artifacts in the heroku toolbelt code. This seems to indicate some kind of issue with the "go" libraries.

No matter what heroku command I attempt, it spews this in addition to any other messages generated by the command. Commands also never seem to complete execution before the process crashes.

So my question is: Is anybody else seeing this and has anyone determined a workaround or fix? Is there a way to file this as a bug with the Heroku development team? Any advice would be appreciated as this is impacting my ability to get work done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this was a bug that was resolved here https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli/commit/201ed5dc774e9f7ee256e80e16c19f6504b36e3f

unfortunately the plugins component here may not be able to autoupdate, so you may have you manually delete `~/.heroku/heroku-cli` to get it fixed.

By the way, the reason you see my username in the traceback is because that's how Go compiles. It's something we're working on resolving though.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Deleting the ~/.heroku/heroku-cli binary seems to have fixed the issue. I'm curious. After deleting that binary, all of the heroku commands that I've tried so far work, but the binary has not been re-created. What exactly does it do?

Comment: it's the new CLI https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli right now it only has a new plugin architecture. If you try to install a plugin that isn't a url (something like `heroku plugins:install heroku-production-check`) then it will install it if it doesn't exist into `~/.heroku/heroku-cli`.

You maybe mistyped a plugins:install command that triggered that.

Comment: Very informative! Thanks again. I hope that this post might help others that randomly stumbled into beta-land :)